# rowspan do not work with thead and tbody

Tags: html, coding-style

I am trying to use rowspan in a table with thead and tbody ex.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">test</td>
       <td>Initials</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>&#160;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But it does not allow me to do it.

Is there a way arround? Or do I have to remove the thead and tbody to be able to use rowspan?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think because a column can not span across the `thead` element. Can you try with a normal row?

Comment: Yes, it does work with normal rows, but it would be handy it there was a way around.

Comment: Why you need thead? You can use styles to style the td's at will. I don't think the semantic lose will be a problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The td would span if there where another tr inside the same thead.

It is what Pekka says: rowspan cannot cross thead or tbody boundaries. So try to move them together.

Comment: You should also use 'TH' elements, for headers within the TBODY.